# Screen will not rotate on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, intel-graphics, display-rotation, intel-atom

I'm running ubuntu on a Intel atom powered cheapo 2in1 tablet (RCA Cambio model w101sa23t2), and after a lot of time everything seems okay except for one huge issue. The screen is rotated 90 degrees and nothing I've tried after extensive googling has worked.

The display menu has all the normal rotation options but when i select one nothing happens

```
xrandr --output default --rotate left
```

says:

```
the output default cannot use rotation "left"
```